# How to level up smithing fast

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Everytime i try to get the ingredients to make smithing potion but they never work but my alchemy is only level 32

Answer (score 1):

Potions won't fail regardless of alchemy level if you use the correct ingredients. [According to the wiki](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Fortify_Smithing), there are 4 ingredients you can use for fortify smithing:

- Blisterwort
- Glowing Mushrooms
- Sabre Cat Tooth
- Spriggan Sap

A common method of leveling smiting is to buy as much iron as possible, make iron daggers, and enchant them. Sell the enchanted daggers for a profit, travel or wait to refresh shop inventory, and repeat.